# items.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using `react-donut-chart` to plot some graph. The code is like this-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DonutChart from 'react-donut-chart';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      value:'',
      text:''
    }

    this.changeText=this.changeText.bind(this);
  }
  changeText(e){
    this.setState({
      text:e.target.value
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <DonutChart data={this.state.text}/>
        <input type='number' value={this.state.text} onChange={this.changeText}/>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

App.propTypes={
  data:propTypes.number
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

[image: error]

When I click on the input box, I get the error

> items.reduce() is not a function

I have already specified the `propTypes`, what else do I need to do.

Comment: yes a prototype , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce, and where is called¿

Comment: proptotype? @ÁlvaroTouzón

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [mcve]. Where are you using `reduce`?

Comment: Array.prototype.reduce, better write is copy it, no error s

Comment: I am not!This is the whole code @evolutionxbox

Comment: @Aayushi Then your error is unrelated to the code example. May you give more of the error information?

Comment: What exactly is that "prop-types" thing? The error is probably coming from the charting code, which expects an array.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the error. Please check @evolutionxbox

Comment: refer to this doc https://codepen.io/danbuda/post/react-js-getdefaultprops-proptypes for details on proptypes @Pointy

Comment: The error is clear: you're passing in a string where the charting code expects an array.  You declare `App.propTypes` as an object, and its `data` property is whatever `propTypes.number` is.

Comment: The data prop you passed should be an array not a string

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.value` will return string object of the data in your input which you are assigning to `state.text`, where `<DonutChart data={array_object_here}/>` expects array of `shape` objects according to documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-donut-chart